# How to optimize lazy loading of sub collection in hibernate

Tags: hibernate, collections, lazy-loading

I have classes: City, Building and ChainBuilding

City has collection of Buildings

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "city_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
protected Set<Building> buildings;

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue(value = "CB")
public class ChainBuilding extends Building {

    public ChainBuilding() {
    }
}

@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorValue(value = "B")
    public class Building {        
        public Building() {
        }
    }
```

I need to get collection of chain buildings and do it the following way:

```
public Set<ChainBuilding> getChainBuildings() {
        Set<ChainBuilding> result = new HashSet<>();
        for (Building item : buildings) {
            if (item instanceof ChainBuilding) {
                result.add((ChainBuilding) item);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Profiler says this (java.util.Set.iterator) is the bottleneck of my app. How can I improve it?
It is possible to add another collection of chainBuildings, and if a new chainbuilding appears I will need to add this object to both collections, but in this case I'm getting an error because hibernate tries to insert the same object into 1 table 2 times. Any ideas? TIA

Comment: You can not do it directly from entity. What are you using to query for City? I mean Criteria api or hql?

Comment: I don't use hql, nor criteria, because it is hard to work with cache in this case. But I prefer hql.

Comment: As I understand you fetch City from db. But you just need to select Buildings from db by city and filter them by disriminator value.

Comment: Yes, but I cannot use queries, because query will load objects from the DB, but I the buildings are in cache, so it is faster to get them from the collection

Comment: But you need to load objects from db. Lazy option on collection works only until you not work with this collection. Hibernate will load all collection elements at the first time you will try to read the collection. So, in you case is better to get only needed collection elements filtered at db layer

Comment: The builds are already loaded from the DB and they are in the cache. There are ~200 buildings, 10 of them are chainbuildings. Getting the chainbuildngs from the cached collection is the slowest operation

Comment: @Shpytyack Artem If it's not in the below 1 ms range than sth. else happens in the background `instanceof` is super fast and adding a few hundred objects to a `HashSet` does not cost anything; did you profile your database while iterating over `buildings` this sounds like a `Select n+1` issue.

Comment: Yes, instanceof is super fast, the problem is in mchange.Set.iterator. Iteration through cached objects is slow.